# jQuery: Post callback-on-success can be 2nd or 3rd parameter?

Tags: jquery

I do understand how to use jquery functions, and how jquery works. According to [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), `$.post` function looks like this:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

I believe this is ok:

```
$.post(url, myOptions, callbackFunctionOnSuccess);
```

**but my question is, Why the below code is *valid*?**

```
$.post(url, callbackFunctionOnSuccess);
```

shouldn't it be something like:

```
$.post(url, null, callbackFunctionOnSuccess);
```

or

```
$.post(url, {}, callbackFunctionOnSuccess);
```

I believe that: jquery checks if the 2nd parameter is a function, then it considers that there is no options (data) passed, and passes the 2nd parameter (the callback-function) to the 3rd parameter. but isn't this kind-of weird for proper implementation? Or is really a best-practice approach?

Comment: It's just how jQuery does it. I'm pretty sure you can find arguments for and against it.

Comment: @FelixKling so you are saying it's ok to do this approach, but it's not best-practice?

Comment: @FelixKling your short comment sounds like the perfect answer to my question! Please post it as an answer I'll tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what makes jQuery so easy to use. This code may look like this:

```
$.post = function(url, options, successCallback) {
  if (options instanceof Function) {
    successCallback = options;
    options = null;
  }
  //rest of code
}
```

Sometimes I use this trick in my projects and it works nicely

**Edit**

Here is original jQuery (1.11.0) `post` method code:

```
function ( url, data, callback, type ) {
    // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        dataType: type,
        data: data,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Comment: As you said, this could be an easier/shorter approach, but it could be also not-so-safe!

Comment: @evilReiko I think this approach is good for those who **write** code, but it might be confusing for those who **read** code, especially if you are not familiar with current library (in our case jQuery)

Comment: I'm faimilar with writing/reading codes, but since I'm developing a plugin based on jQuery, I like to play it safe

Comment: @evilReiko I didn't mean you when I said about familiarity with code, sorry for that :) I'm not a native English speaker. Since jQuery uses this approach in many methods (`animate`, `on`, `post`, `get`, etc) I think it is normal to use it when writing jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `arguments` object, you can accept function arguments even if they aren't pre-defined.

```
function goHere(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

If you try to call this function as `goHere(3, 5, 10);`, no errors will occur.  The only thing that will be different is the extra argument in this case will be ignored since it doesn't get addressed.

```
function goHere(a, b) {
    var values;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if(typeof arguments[i] === 'string') // Assume this is "url" since it's the only string
        if(typeof arguments[i] === 'object') // Assume this is "data" since it's the only object;
        if(typeof arguments[i] === 'function') //  Assume this is the callback
        values += arguments[i];
    }
    return values;  // For fun.  No real reason.
}
```

## [Experience it in 3D](http://jsfiddle.net/DJSgJ/)

This is how you can do what you're asking.  Here is a little more light reading on the subject:  **[Function arguments on Javascript.info](http://javascript.info/tutorial/arguments)**